# How do I add testing to the data access layer methods?

Tags: go, mocking

I am having a lot of difficulty in writing tests for my graphql resolvers.

Let's assume I have a resolver, which handles the creation of a new user.
The resolver would look something like:

```
func (r *mutationResolver) CreateUser(ctx context.Context, name string) (*model.User, error) {
    u, err := doa.AddUser(ctx, client, index, name)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Could not add User to db")
        return nil, err
    }
    fmt.Println("Insertion Successful")
    return u, nil
}
```

My doa layer has the `AddUser` method.

```
func AddUser(ctx context.Context, client *elastic.Client, index string, name string) (*model.User, error) {
    u := &model.User{
        UserID: uuid.New().String(),
        Name:   name,
    }
    s, err := utils.ParseToString(u)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    _, err = client.Index().
             Index(index).
             BodyString(s).
             Do(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error Storing the User")
        return nil, err
    }
    return u, err
}
```

I know I would be using a testing library like `gomock` or `testify`, but I don't know how to structure the code at all. How should I write the interfaces that the testing library would call?

Answer (score 0):

For starters I would pull out the creation of the model.User type since that is a high level object that defines the policy that user IDs will be uuid. You don't want that entangled with a lower layer where you are interacting with elastic search. I would just pass the user in. Also you may want to test that users are created as expected. Having this logic in AddUser will complicate the testing.

Next I would use an interface to pass in the dependency on elastic.Client. That will allow you to mock it and see that AddUser is using that dependency as expected (i.e. adding the user).

You may even want to create a new type that holds the interfaces to your low level dependencies and provides AddUser as a method. You could then create an interface that has AddUser in it to separate clients to the interface from the low level details.

[When to mock](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2014/05/10/WhenToMock.html)

Here is an example. I think the link above offers good advice on limiting this to architectural boundaries. You can see how it can get out of hand quickly.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/olivere/elastic"
)

type User struct {}

type Repo interface {
    AddUser(User) error
}

type ElasticClient interface {
    Index() ElasticIndex
}

type ElasticIndex interface {
    Index(string) ElasticIndex
    BodyString(string) ElasticIndex
    Do(context.Context) (*elastic.IndexResponse, error)
}

type MockElasticClient struct {
    Log *[]string
    index MockElasticIndex
}

type MockElasticIndex struct {
    Log *[]string
}

func NewMockElasticClient() *MockElasticClient {
    var log []string
    return &MockElasticClient{
        Log: &log,
        index: MockElasticIndex{&log},
    }
}

func (c *MockElasticClient) Index() ElasticIndex {
    *c.Log = append(*c.Log, "Client.Index()")
    return &c.index
}

func (i *MockElasticIndex) Index(s string) ElasticIndex {
    *i.Log = append(*i.Log, fmt.Sprintf("Index.Index(%s)", s))
    return i
}

func (i *MockElasticIndex) BodyString(s string) ElasticIndex {
    *i.Log = append(*i.Log, fmt.Sprintf("Index.BodyString(%s)", s))
    return i
}

func (i *MockElasticIndex) Do(ctx context.Context) (*elastic.IndexResponse, error) {
    *i.Log = append(*i.Log, "Index.Do()")
    return nil, nil
}

// Use a wrapped client to deal with the fact that elastic
// returns their own types and not interfaces.
type WrappedElasticClient struct {
    wrapped *elastic.Client
}

type WrappedElasticIndexService struct {
    wrapped *elastic.IndexService
}

func (c WrappedElasticClient) Index() ElasticIndex {
    return WrappedElasticIndexService{c.wrapped.Index()}
}

func (i WrappedElasticIndexService) Index(s string) ElasticIndex {
    i.wrapped.Index(s)
    return i
}

func (i WrappedElasticIndexService) BodyString(s string) ElasticIndex {
    i.BodyString(s)
    return i
}

func (i WrappedElasticIndexService) Do(ctx context.Context) (*elastic.IndexResponse, error) {
    return i.wrapped.Do(ctx)
}

type ElasticRepo struct {
    ctx context.Context
    client ElasticClient
}

func (r ElasticRepo) AddUser(u User) error {
    s, err := utils.ParseToString(u)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    _, err = r.client.Index().
        Index("some index").
        BodyString(s).
        Do(r.ctx)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error Storing the User")
        return err
    }

    return err
}

func main() {
    m := NewMockElasticClient()
    r := ElasticRepo{
        ctx: nil,
        client: m,
        //client: WrappedElasticClient{&elastic.Client{}},
    }
    r.AddUser(User{})

    fmt.Println(m.Log)
}
```

Comment: " Next I would use an interface to pass in the dependency on elastic.Client."
I am having trouble over here. What do I pass when trying to mock it?

Comment: I added a fairly complete example. The index is hard coded because I am not sure where you want to get that data from. It probably doesn't make sense in the repo interface since it is specific to elastic. I'd probably have as a piece internal data that the repo implementation manages. Also for elastic you will need to wrap their methods so you can return an interface and decouple from their types to support your mocking.

Comment: The log is just to show you that you can pull out any kind of data and check it in your testing. Here it is just showing the order of the calls and what values you passed in.